# What is this view mode and how do I go back to the default one?

Tags: 3d-view

I pressed some button accidentally while trying to do something else and now I have dots everywhere. It's kinda useful since I can see through the object, but I kinda just want to go back to the default view. How do I do that?

[image: wot]

Comment: upper right buttons, the one with two squares in it named "X ray" (it is blue, as checked in your screen capture).

Comment: Thanks @lemon! Do you want to answer it with that? Oh, and what's the shortcut for that?

Comment: Mitch, no. But you can if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called X-Ray, and can be toggled with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Here's a screenshot of the preferences window where I found the keyboard shortcut:

[image: keymap settings]

Thanks to @lemon. :)

Comment: Answer thanks to you Mitch, upvoted!

Comment: it's rather alt Z, aka Show Whole Scene Transparent option on the top menu bar, you can switch it on and off in whatever display mode you are. Shift Z is to switch to Wireframe display + Transparent

Comment: Oh. I'm having a hard time seeing the difference between these two features..